# Intellij Highlighting Error with No Errors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, ide

Intelij only shows me the errors in the file but not in the whole project.

I have intelij freshly installed, flutter doctor correct, and the plugin installed.

And I have created a project from 0 as an example.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1O6f.png)

I need to know how I can see the errors in the problems tab.

Answer (score 0):

As per IntelliJ official documentation:

**Currently, the project-wide analysis works only in Java projects. It might work incorrectly in projects that combine Java with other languages, such as Kotlin or Scala.**

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-and-project-analysis.html#project-wide-analysis

Personally I think VS Code works best with flutter. Or just stick with Android Studio since it's basically IntelliJ but adapted specifically for... mobile development (including flutter support)